# Ignore array item if it doesn't exist in slicer items (slicer filtering with array)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, olap-cube

I have encountered a problem when filtering an OLAP based pivot table slicer with items from an array.

I have an Array consisting of machine numbers that are identical to slicer items captions, that looks like this:

`machines = Array("Machine1", "Machine2", "Machine3" etc.. )`

and I want to use this array to filter the slicer using:

`ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("MachinesSlicer").VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(machines)`

And it works fine until there is a machine number in array that is not visible in the slicer items (for example due to other slicers filtering, such as date etc).
Is there a way to bypass those items that cause the problem?

I've tried to create a new array, looping through the slicer items and comparing them to array items using:

```
For Each machName In machines
    For Each si1 In sl1.SlicerItems
        If si1.Caption = machName Then
        TestArray = TestArray & Chr(34) & si1.Caption & Chr(34) & Chr(44)
        End If
    Next si1
Next machName
```

But what it does is it creates an array that has a single element that is a string looking like:

`"Machine1", "Machine2", Machine3" ...etc`

But I need these elements to be seperated in order to pass them into the VisibleSlicerItemList.

Maybe some of you will have any idea how to resolve this problem.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore my previous answer, blonde moment. You need an array of course.

You can create a dynamic array based on `sl1.SlicerItems`

```
Dim dynArr()
Dim i as Integer 'Long
Dim si1

For Each si1 In sl1.SlicerItems
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve dynArr(1 To i)
    dynArr(i) = si1.Caption
Next
```

Pozdrawiam kolege ;)

Comment: Thank you, I will try that next week, but it seems it's what I needed! Również pozdrawiam :)